# Regex : Getting STYLE tag height and Width values in JAVA

Tags: regex

As im struggling with REGEX to get img tag attribute STYLE element values, i.e, Width and Height.
I got the way to get the value of STYLE  and SRC by,

```
<img\\b(?>\\s+(?:style=\"([^\"]*)\"|src=\"([^\"]*)\")|[^\\s>]+|\\s+)*>
```

Now i need too get the value of HEIGHT and WIDTH of the STYLE TAG, Please help me.

Orginal Code:

`style=\"width:100px; height:100px\" height=\"\" src=\".png\" alt=\"87\` 
where it was present inside the IMAGE TAG.

Where i need output as,

```
width:100px as seperate (i.e, $1)
```

and

```
height:100px as seperate (i.e, $2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As always, make sure you have very specific constraints on your input data or you should be using a html parser.

Also, since the contents of `style` are CSS, you need to be able to make the same strong assumptions about the contents of the attribute, or you should also use a parser.

The best/easiest way to do this is to have a second, separate, regex for matching the style rules. Assuming you *only* have `height` and `width`, and assuming they always exist, and assuming they always come in the same order:

```
\s*height\s*:\s*([^;]*);\s*width\s*:\s*([^;"]*);?
```

See all the assumptions? This is why parsers exist.